# How to shift chars in a character array without a temp?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, c-strings

I'm wondering if there's any way to shift all characters from an index one position to the right, given that there is enough space allocated for it.

I got hints by my teacher that it can be done without an auxiliary variable and using the `<cstring>` library.

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[100] = "Welcome to hell!";
    strcpy(str+4, str+3);
    cout << str; //Welccccccco hell!!
                 //Expected: Welccome to hell (to double the c so i can insert whitespace)
    return 0;
}
```

I know that this function works with pointers as parameters, so calling it with the same string can mess things up. But is it possible in a way? I found that strcpy(s+i, s+j) gives an unexpected result if i > j. Why? Also, what's the alternative?

Comment: The alternative is `std::memmove`.

Comment: IIRC `strcpy` have the same issue as `memcpy` and it can't be used to copy to overlapping areas.

Comment: I don't think anything in `<cstring>` would be useful, but if you had a shelf of books and needed to shift all the books to the right, which end would you start with?

Comment: Oh now I get it, I can't access the next element anymore if I paste over it. Anyway, besides this mistake, I really though maybe there was something from `<cstring>`. I got it, for loop from the right. Thanks

Comment: It can; `std::memmove` _is_ in cstring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you get undefined behaviour when using strcpy with overlapping ranges.

From https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

> ...the size of the array pointed by destination shall be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with source.

To see why this is an issue, we can look at some of the implementations of `strcpy` discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476627/strcpy-implementation-in-c), and see that the code copies from the source buffer to the destination buffer until the null terminator character `'\0'` is reached. When calling `strcpy(str+3, str+4)`, you are always copying the same character, then advancing and reading again the same character you just copied, so the null terminator is never reached.

Perhaps there is some difference or safety check in the implementation of `strcpy` you are using, as it does not overwrite the entire string, and stops after some time. Or perhaps this is the result of compiler optimizations, which are allowed to assume you don't do things the library functions say not to do (i.e. that your code does not invoke undefined behaviour).

It's not clear from your question whether your teacher suggests using other tools in `<cstring>` to write code to accomplish your goal, or whether your teacher thinks that there is an exact function which already does what you want.

I would suggest that rather than starting from the middle of the string, you start at the end, and move all characters down one, to leave the doubling you desire. If the purpose of doing this shift is always to insert a space, you could build this space insertion into the same function as well.

As an aside, if you are working in C++, it is typically best to avoid C-style strings unless absolutely necessary. You should instead prefer using the standard library's `std::string`.

Comment: Yes yes. It was a question from an academic standpoint. I know and I use std::string but I appreciate the addition. You answered my question fully.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy(str+4, str+3);` reads characters from `str+3` until it finds a `\0`. However, it reads a character from one position then writes to the next position in the array, hence it never finds a `\0`. More formally, `strcpy(str+4,str+3)` invokes undefined behavior. Output of the code could be anything.

You can use  [`std::reverse_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) that avoids the issue of reading the character that just has been overwritten by starting at the back:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[100] = "Welcome to hell!";
    std::copy_backward(str+3,str+std::strlen(str),str+std::strlen(str)+1);
    cout << str;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qYvvExPP5)

The 3 arguments are start of the source, `str+3`, end of the source, `str+std::strlen(str)`, and end of the destination, `end_of_source+1`.

Comment: this is still undefined behaviour *Copies all elements in the range [first, last) starting from first and proceeding to last, to another range beginning at d_first.
 If d_first is in [first, last), the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @0xbachmann I think I confused left and right :D

Comment: @0xbachmann fixed the code, no more UB

Comment: I like it, just what i just manually crafted, did not know about copy backwards.

Comment: @0xbachmann me neither. I am curious how it compares to `std::copy` with reverse iterators. Though after that silly mistake of confusing left and right I rather take a break

Comment: [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MMYxa7rc4) seems to work the same as `copy_backwards`, note the reverse order of the source iterators though

Answer (score 2):

It you insist on doing it with `<cstring>` (to stay within the taught material for example), then:

```cpp
memmove( str+4, str+3, sizeof(str) - 4);
```

or more generally:

```cpp
memmove( str+n+1, 
         str+n, 
         sizeof(str) - n - 1);
```

Noting that that relies on `str` being an array rather than a pointer.  Otherwise you need to know the actual string length:

```cpp
memmove( str+n+1, 
         str+n, 
         strlen(str + n) );
```

but `strlen()` necessarily iterates the string to find the end, so there performance wise it may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy)

> The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap.

Are you tied to using C-strings? Using `std::string` allows for this:

```
std::string string("Welcome to hell!");
std::cout << string.insert(3, " ");
```

To avoid copy of the whole sting on insertion, because more memory is needed, you may call `reserve` to tell the string how much space is needed in advance:

```
std::string string;
string.reserve(100);
string = "Welcome to hell!";
```

In case you cannot use `std::string`, the following function foes the trick:

```
void shift_right(char* const str, size_t from, size_t shift_amount) {
    const size_t size = std::strlen(str);
    for (unsigned i = size; i > from; --i) {
        str[i + shift_amount] = str[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[100] = "Welcome to hell!";
    shift_right(str, 3, 1);
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Moving the elements starting from the back does not override the elements needed afterwards. **Note** `size + shift_amount + 1` should be less than the whole `char` array. If you shift more than the `size - from`, then make sure that you fill the values, otherwise there may be a stray `\0` or garbage in the middle of your string.

Comment: Well yes, I'm tied to using arrays of characters. I appreciate the viewpoint with strings.